# Filtering a list by a predicate and putting the results into a new list

Tags: list, kotlin, nodes

Im pretty new to programming,so I need to filter a list by a predicate and make a new list of the results without changing the list I filtered. My Problem is, that always all elements of the list to be filtered get put into the newList, and i dont know why.

Edit: I am not allowed to use build in - functions like filter.

```
fun filter(predicate: (Order) -> Boolean): OrderProcessing {
        
var currentNode = first
        
var newList: OrderProcessing = OrderProcessing()
       
while (currentNode != null) {
            var next = currentNode.next
            if (predicate(currentNode.order)) {

                if (newList.first != null) {
                    var newerNode = newList.first
                    while (newerNode != null) {
                        newerNode = newerNode.next
                    }
                    currentNode.next = null
                    newerNode?.next = currentNode
                    println(currentNode.next)
                }
                else newList.first = currentNode
            }
                currentNode = next
        }
        println(newList)
        return newList
```

Comment: What's the problem with predefined implementation of [List.filter()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html)? By the way what is `OrderProcessing`?

Comment: I am not allowed to use predefined implementations, i forgot to mention that, im sorry. Orderprocessing is the class which defines the structure of my list

Comment: Hint: what does `newerNode` get set to?  Is it ever non-null by the time you get to `newerNode?.next = currentNode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin has a function for this, `filter` which will do what you want:

```kotlin
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3)

val result = list.filter { it > 2 }

println(result.joinToString()) // [3]
```

If you are not allowed to use `filter` you can just re-implement it:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.filter(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): List<T> {
    val result = mutableListOf<T>()
    forEach { if(predicate(it)) result.add(it) }
    return result
}
```